# responsive content of webpage

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I use media query and i want content on my web page be responsive.

is this code ok?

```
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){


.navmob{margin-top:0px; margin-left:-100px; margin-right:100px !important; }
.sidebar { display: none; } 

    #navmenu {margin-top:10px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:100px; }

    .content {width:auto; height:auto; margin-left:100px; margin-top:-50px;}

    .contentsing{ width:500px; height:auto; margin-left:auto;  margin-right:auto; margin-top:-50px !important;}

      body{

        background-image:none    !important;
        background-color:#000000 !important;
        font-size:12px !important;
         }  

      }
```

and why content is not responsive... Here is [example](http://stefanvblog.com/category/news/)

Here is code of my [index](http://pastebin.com/2q5REF05)

Comment: can you correct it? i don't know what to do ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is allot of bugs i found  in console. Any way i cannot solve all of them but i can tell you, you need to work on width when you make a template responsive. These are some css line from i try to manage  your template, Hop that help you
Put them as it is

```
@media(max-width:714px){

.posts .post-item{width:96%}
.text5{width:100%}
#navmenu ul{width:90%}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing your responsiveness by resizing your browser, `device-width` will not take effect. This is because the  width of your computer screen does not change.

Use `max-width/min-width`. It targets the rendering area on the screen, therefore, when you resize, the CSS will take effect.

**`device-width` targets the screens resolution.**

**`max-width/min-wdith` targets the screens rendering area.**

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way to go about a responsive website. You need a series of media queries to cater for:

desktop 1024px
ipad 768px
iphone 320px

Once you have these breakpoints set up the site will respond as expected, all content needs to be set to % in terms of width so it can adjust accordingly. Also do not use px use em for font sizes as this will auto re adjust for you.

Look into using a front end framework such as bootstrap as this does a lot of the hard work for you by using a 12 column grid layout system.